# How to cancel Mac store update?

Tags: macos, mac-appstore

Is it possible to cancel a paused app update? There is no cancel option in the App Store; only resume is there.

Answer (score 11):

The secret is `OPTION` key.
Press that and that `resume` button will turn in to `cancel`.

http://www.cultofmac.com/224342/cancel-instead-of-pausing-your-mac-app-store-updates-os-x-tips/

Comment: This no longer works in OS X 10.10.3 App Store 2.0 :/

Comment: works great on 10.10.5, went to launchpad and pressed the OPTION key and i was able to cancel the update for Xcode

Comment: works in sierra (10.12.5)

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem, but I couldn't stop it using the option key. I just disconnected my Mac from the network and waited some seconds, and the download failed and it couldn't resume again. After that, I turned off automatic updates.